# Expand array so user can select best option and input into variable

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to figure out how to do the following.

1. Read a text file with phone numbers in a list that are available each number on a separate line.
2. Output the available list to the script user to be able to select the best one.
3. Input the `$number` into another command to add it to the new user.

I have the following so far

```
$numbers = gc 'C:\temp\file.txt'
```

I can output the data by using `$numbers[1]`, `$numbers[2]`, etc., but how can I output this to look good and allow the user to select the best number with all options in the text file? I can do it manually obviously, but if I do 3 x `$numbers[1]`, `$numbers[2]`, `$numbers[3]` it will miss the numbers 4, 5, 6 etc.

Comment: `Get-Content | Out-Gridview -Passthru`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Something like this :

```
$selected=Get-Content "c:\temp\phone.txt" | Out-Gridview -Title "Select your choice" -OutputMode Single

if ($selected)
{
    Write-Host "your choice is $selected" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$numbers = Get-Content 'C:\temp\file.txt' 
$i = 1

foreach($n in $numbers){
    Write-host "Number $i - $n"
    $i++
}

$n = Read-host "Choose a number"

$chosenNumber = $number[$n-1]
```